# AMP Script Marketng Cloud EncryptSymmetric

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, encryption, decrypt

I would like to encrpt a emailaddress with AES and decrypt  with a other java appclication.
I try

```
%%[SET @encData=EncryptSymmetric(emailaddr, "AES;mode=cbc;padding=pkcs7", @null, "1111222233334444", @null, "0000000000000000", @null, "00000000000000000000000000000000")
]%%
```

this works for encryption, but the can't decrypt this email.
I have try  a lot of implementations : I got errors like this:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

my initVector is in my javaclass :
  byte[] initialVector   =new  byte[] { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 };
```

It's 16 bytes long, but in the AMPScript function 32 chars?

What is my problem?

Comment: Looks like an issue with how you are decoding. Can you [review this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988552/javax-crypto-badpaddingexception-pad-block-corrupted) and confirm if that fixes your issue?

Comment: There are only certain SFMC encryption methods that you can encrypt outside of the platform -- at least that have been released in the wild.